# RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","message":" There are no records of this type

Tags: javascript, workflow, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Okay everyone, very much through the looking glass on this one.
Many thanks to Barmar, Kryton and bknights whose wisdom has helped get me this far.

The script has changed and is now below. I can upload it and generate a script record and it does actually attempt to run, but now I am getting this error:

*"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","message":"There are no records of this type.","stack":["createError(N/error)","initiateWorkflow(/SuiteScripts/grn20.js:9)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","details":"There are no records of this type.","userEvent":"aftersubmit","stackTrace":["createError(N/error)","initiateWorkflow(/SuiteScripts/grn20.js:9)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}*

But the record definitely does exist, the ID number and workflow ID are as specified in the workflow.

What else could be causing this problem?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

**Edit - I have been told that the record ID below should refer to the internal ID of the item, this makes no sense, the workflow I am trying to initiate is designed to change fields on multiple items, why would I need to specify a single item in the script?**

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define(['N/workflow', 'N/search', 'N/error', 'N/record'],
    function (workflow, search, error, record) {
        function initiateWorkflow(scriptContext) {
               var workflowInstanceId = workflow.initiate({
                recordType: 'inventoryitem',
                recordId: 35,
                workflowId: 'customworkflow14'
            });
            var inventoryitemRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.INVENTORY_ITEM,
                id: 35
            });
        }
        return {
            afterSubmit: initiateWorkflow
        };
    });
```

Comment: When you indent it properly you can see that you have an extra `)` after the function, so the `return` is not inside the function. Remove the `)` before `return`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, when I did this the error changed to - "missing ) after argument list"
I think this is why I put the parentheses in in the first instance. I am struggling with this script.

Comment: Sorry, it's the whole `})` line that needs to be removed. As above, if you use your editor's auto-indent feature you should be able to see the structure problems.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I appreciate you trying to help, though I feel stuck in a cycle of error madness that has been occurring for several hours now.
For example the error is now :

"Fail to evaluate script: All SuiteScript API Modules are unavailable while executing your define callback."

Comment: I'm not familiar with SuiteScript, so I can't help you with that. But that's a different problem, unrelated to the syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for your help getting to this point, at least I am down to hopefully a final error :)

Comment: Thank you, I gave that a go and it took me to another stack overflow page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926577/netsuite-getting-error-fail-to-evaluate-script-all-suitescript-api-modules-a
However the solution in this instance seems to indicate that he wasn't using the RETURN on his callback function, but I am using RETURN, so not sure I am any wiser.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the return. I think it's saying that you can't call `task.create()` inside the callback.

Comment: If you are in a UserEvent script and have some logic to run on inventory items you might try skipping the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 issues that I can see:

1. You need to use `define()` rather than `require()`.  Note from NetSuite documents below:

> Note This sample script uses the require function so that you can copy
> it into the SuiteScript Debugger and test it. You must use the define
> function in an entry point script (the script you attach to a script
> record and deploy). For more information, see SuiteScript 2.x Script
> Basics and SuiteScript 2.x Script Types.

2. You need to implement an entry point function in your `return` block.  For a User Event Script as this is, that means you need one of `beforeLoad`, `beforeSubmit` or `afterSubmit`.

For your example, your script would end up looking something like this:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

define(['N/task'],
    function (task) {
        function workflowTask(scriptContext) {
            task.create({
                taskType: task.TaskType.WORKFLOW_TRIGGER
            });
            workflowTask.recordType = 'INVENTORY_ITEM';
            workflowTask.recordId = 'Item';
            workflowTask.workflowId = 'customworkflow14';
            var taskId = workflowTask.submit();
        }
        return {
            afterSubmit: workflowTask
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Amazing. thank you. I know I have a long way to go yet, but I wanted to get the script onto the sandbox and start experimenting.  Your advice worked perfectly and the initial set of errors are all gone. Thank you, I am truly grateful for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong with what you are doing. This really is a RTM situation.

You may be just trying to exercise the API so don't really care about the type of script but Netsuite does. It parses the NScriptType annotation and is rejecting your script as being non-conforming.

A user event script has a shape like:

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define([module list], function(modules...){
    function beforeRecordSubmit(ctx){...} // these functions can use SuiteScript API Modules
    function beforeRecordSubmit(ctx){...}
    function afterRecordSubmit(ctx){...}

// you cannot use Suitescript API Modules outside of the returned functions

return {
    beforeLoad: beforeRecordLoad,
    beforeSubmit: beforeRecordSubmit,
    afterSubmit: afterRecordSumbit
};

});
```

Also these lines:

```
workflowTask.recordType = 'INVENTORY_ITEM';
workflowTask.recordId = 'Item';
```

look like they are just hopeful guesses. There is online help for all of this if you are logged in to Netsuite.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you feedback, I understand I have a lot to learn and adapt but this is one part of a huge project I have been tasked with and I am not a programmer.

I consulted the online help, the description for the record type says:

 
"The record type ID of the workflow base record. Use values from the record.Type enum. This is the Record Type field on the Workflow Definition Page."

The workflow definition page says 

"Record Type
Item (Inventory Part)"

But Item (Inventory Part) says 'Invalid Record Type'

May I ask for your guidance on that?

Comment: `recordType` will probably just be `'item'` You might try `'inventoryitem'` but workflow target records include item not item types. 
`recordId` will be the internal id of the inventory item for which you are triggering the work flow.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out it was 'inventoryitem'. I appreciate your input. The script is now attempting to run but I have another error stating that the record does not exist and that there are no records for this record type. Which is maddening, because the record definitely exists and the details are those in the script. I have detailed above. If there is any chance you get a couple of minutes today to have a glance I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Harkening back to this I've just re-read your last comment. "recordId will be the internal id of the inventory item" - The workflow itself is designed to action against multiple items, not a single item, that would be fruitless, the idea of the exercise is that when record X is submitted, the workflow initiates and updates records Y Z and U.